# What is a coproduct in an enriched category?

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory, enriched-category-theory

Does anybody know how to define coproducts in enriched categories ? For example I was wondering if they could be thought of as some kind of [weighted colimits](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/weighted+colimit#:%7E:text=A%20weighted%20colimit%20is%20a,the%20concept%20of%20weighted%20limit.). I am particularly interested in if/how coproducts are defined in [categories enriched over weighted sets](https://www.emis.de/journals/JHRS/volumes/2007/n2a9/v2n2a9hl.pdf) (that is, additively weighted categories).

Comment: Do you mean something other than the general definition of coproduct as a colimit over a discrete diagram?

Comment: I would be happy just to understand what you mean by that. In particular, what is a discrete diagram in an enriched category, and what weight/indexing functor should be used ?

Comment: Coproducts are conical colimits. The weight is the constant weight with value the monoidal unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your base of enrichment has a $\rm copy$ morphism, there is a functor

$$ \Delta : {\cal A} \to {\cal A} \boxtimes {\cal A} $$

where the codomain is using the monoidal structure on the 2-category ${\cal V}\text{-Cat}$ inherited from $\cal V$. $\Delta$ "copies" objects and morphisms, in the obvious sense (you need $\cal V$ to have a $\rm copy$ map in order to define $\Delta_{AB} : {\cal A}(A,A') \to {\cal A}(A,A') \otimes {\cal A}(A,A')$).

**Definition.** An "enriched coproduct" is a left adjoint for $\Delta$.

One can probably argue differently and use a certain discrete weight, but I can't say from the top of my head if these definitions are equivalent:

Let $\cal I[2]$ be the discrete $\cal V$-category on a two-element set: $\hom(x,y)$ is the monoidal unit if $x=y$, and the initial object otherwise (I am assuming the base of enrichment has all limits and colimits needed to state everything I need, plus symmetry of course). The binary coproduct of two objects $X,Y\in\cal A$ is a colimit for a functor $F : {\cal I[2]} \to \cal A$ which is defined on objects sending $0\in [2]$ to $X$, and $1\in [2]$ to $Y$, weighted by the functor constant... at the monoidal unit? At the terminal object?

Comment: Wait, I'm not *exactly* sure this works :-) I have to check a few details, or we have to check them together... To guide my definition I used a common principle that -for example- defines categorically a quantale. But the ultimate test would be to check whether this definition gives the correct answer in a "concrete" enriched category, for example $\sf Ab$ over itself has coproducts.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a $\mathcal{V}$-enriched category and let $A$ and $B$ be objects in $\mathcal{C}$.
A $\mathcal{V}$-enriched coproduct $A + B$ is an object in $\mathcal{C}$ together with morphisms $j : I \to \mathcal{C} (A, A + B)$ and $k : I \to \mathcal{C} (B, A + B)$ in $\mathcal{V}$ such that, for each object $C$ in $\mathcal{C}$, each object $V$ in $\mathcal{V}$, and each pair of morphisms $f : V \to \mathcal{C} (A, C)$ and $g : V \to \mathcal{C} (B, C)$ in $\mathcal{V}$, there is a unique morphism $[f, g] : V \to \mathcal{C} (A + B, C)$ such that the following diagrams commute:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
V \otimes I @>{[f, g] \otimes j}>> \mathcal{C}(A + B, C) \otimes \mathcal{C} (A, A + B) \\
@V{\cong}VV @VV{\circ}V \\
V @>>{f}> \mathcal{C} (A, C)
\end{CD}$$
$$\begin{CD}
V \otimes I @>{[f, g] \otimes k}>> \mathcal{C}(A + B, C) \otimes \mathcal{C} (B, A + B) \\
@V{\cong}VV @VV{\circ}V \\
V @>>{g}> \mathcal{C} (B, C)
\end{CD}$$

If $\mathcal{V}$ has binary (cartesian!) products, this can be more succinctly expressed as saying that the coproduct is a $\mathcal{V}$-enriched representation of the $\mathcal{V}$-enriched functor $\mathcal{C} (A, -) \times \mathcal{C} (B, -)$.
(Expanding the definitions here actually yields many further conditions that I have omitted from the above because they are automatically satisfied.)
If $\mathcal{V}$ has enough limits and colimits, this can be expressed as a special case of $\mathcal{V}$-enriched conical colimits, which are in turn special cases of $\mathcal{V}$-enriched weighted colimits.
The details are in Kelly's textbook.